# Fabric JS how to address a SVG

Tags: fabricjs

I have loaded a SVG on the canvas. Everything works, but I have difficulties to address the object.
Here is the code:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL("images/Achse3.svg",function(objects)
  {

          var achse1 = new fabric.PathGroup(objects, {
            left: 127,
            top: 70,
            opacity: 0.5,
            scaleX: 1.25,
            scaleY: 1.25
          });

          canvas.add(achse1);
      //canvas.renderAll();
  });
```

I tried to address the SVG via canvas.item, but the results are very strange. Depending on the value in the sample:

```
canvas.item(11).set('top',this.value);
```

The items change. How can I address the item I loaded. I tried it with

```
canvas.achse1.set('top',this.value);
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a reference to your `PathGroup`, you have just to set the related properties of it.

Try yourself the runnable snippet below if it meets your needs.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c'), svg_group;

fabric.loadSVGFromURL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Olympic_rings_with_white_rims.svg", function(objects) {

  svg_group = new fabric.PathGroup(objects, {
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    scaleX: .1,
    scaleY: .1
  });

  canvas.add(svg_group);
  $('#b').on('click', () => {
    svg_group.set('top', 100);
    canvas.renderAll();
  })
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dashed #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width=300 height=150></canvas>
<button id='b'>move it</button>
```

Comment: Hi, I´m sorry, but this is not working form me. Maybe it is related to the variable declaration within the loadSVGfromUrl function.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I used VAR to declare the variable within the loadSVG function. So the variable was just local within the function. The declaration without VAR did the job. Now the variable is global and can be addressed from outside the function.